# How can I create a button or link that automatically downloads a file based on a URL?

Tags: html, forms, url, server, download

Here's a website: [Download link generator](https://adresults.com/tools/download-link-generator)

And here's the `form` in the page source:

```
<form id="download" class="download_action" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="download_action">
<label for="url">Please enter the URL you would like to save as a file:</label>
<div class="field">
<input id="url" class="text mr-3" name="keyword" type="text">
<input class="submit" title="Save target as" type="submit" value="Save target as">
</div>
<div class="tool-target" style="padding-bottom: 10px;"> </div>
<div id="return"> </div>
<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="5c9a47c6d6" /><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/tools/download-link-generator" />
</form>
```

It seems to be a server-side solution, but I don't have much information about servers and how they do it. I wonder how it works exactly. Can similar projects be built for free, or do I need paid hosting and a server plus a vast knowledge of running it? **What I finally want is a link/button that will force download.**

Comment: Could you get it to work?

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I don't know where to run it. Initially, I had a free host like GitHub Pages in mind, but it doesn't seem to support server-side languages.

Comment: You can set up a PHP or Node server locally.

Comment: You can also search for "Free php hosting".
Please mark the answer as correct, then you can ask a new question if you run into problems setting it up.

Comment: @Mori, do you want it accessible from the internet, or is this for your own personal use?

Comment: @Yarin_007: Yes, I want it accessible from the internet. But does it really make a difference?

Comment: well... spinning up a local server is easier than dealing with "free web hosting" like pythonanywhere or 000WebHost or "AWS lambda functions" or setting up a vps.

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass: Your answer is still the best one I've received.  Why did you remove it? I was going to give you the 500 reputation bounty after the bounty ended. Would you mind putting your answer back?

Comment: It was deleted by a moderator.

Answer (score 1):

Evidently I was wrong. pythonanywhere is really easy.
(But you must use any paid plan in order to access most outside servers (i.e. get files from any website you want)). As of right now, the cheapest plan they have is $5 a month.

**Stackoverflow isn't a code-writing service.**
But enjoy this little exception.

here's a basic implementation of what you've asked for:

We're gonna use an HTTP server written in Python, using a framework called Flask.
That server will provide two functions:

1. Serve us that basic form you've described
2. allow us to request from the backend the file we want, and it will force our web browser to download it (and not display it, for example)

**Step 1**

*Create a "pythonanywhere" account.*
**Attention:** your website will be hosted on `username.pythonanywhere.com`, choose wisely.

hit "open web tab"*
[image]

**Step 2**

*Select the latest Flask version in "add new web app"* (3.10 in this case) and hit Next.
[image]

**Step 3**

verify the website works, click on that link, you should see "Hello from Flask!".

[image]

**Step 4**

Go to the "Files" tab, enter the `mysite` directory
[image]

and create a new directory called "templates"

[image]

**Step 5**

Create a new file called `index.html`,
and put this html in it:

(css and form taken from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_form.asp))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
input[type=text], select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}

div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>
<body>

<h3>File Proxy</h3>

<div>
  <form method="POST" action="/download"> <!-- notice the @app.route("/download"...) in the flask file -->
    <label for="fpath">File Path</label>
    <input type="text" id="fpath" name="fpath" placeholder="Path...">  
  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hit save

**Step 6**

Go back to the "Files" tab, and enter `mysite` directory again.

edit the `flask_app.py` file
[image]

and replace the code in it with the following:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, Response
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)

content_type_to_extension={"text/html": ".html"}

FALLBACK_EXTENSION=".bin"

# get the path from the form, GET it ourselves, and return it with a content-type that will force the client's browser to download it and not attempt to display it.
@app.route("/download", methods=["POST"])
def loadData():
    data = request.form["fpath"]
    
    r = requests.get(data)
    response = Response(
        r.content,
        status=r.status_code,
        content_type="application/stream"
        # content_type=r.headers['content-type']
    )
 
    # basic naming attempt. if it has a uri (text after the last /), let's (maybe falsly, this is a POC) assume that it has a file extension. (you can add regex tests and whatnot)
    try:
        fname = data.replace('://','')
        fname = fname[fname.rindex("/")+1:]
        assert (len(fname) > 1)
    except (IndexError, ValueError, AssertionError):
        fname = data.replace("/", "-")
        ext = content_type_to_extension.get(r.headers['content-type'].split(";")[0], FALLBACK_EXTENSION) # if we can't find ther correct extension, fallback to .bin
        fname += ext

    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = f'attachment; filename={fname}'
    return response


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html") # that html file in /templates

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Hit save

[image]

**Step 7**

Go back to the "web" tab, and hit that green "reload" button. (or the blue reload icon next to the save in the `flask_app.py` edit panel)

And go to your website.

The `requests` library requires a `schema` to be specified.
so don't forget the `http(s)://` or add it via python.

[image]

If you don't have a paid account, checking out the error logs in the "web" tab tells us

```
OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))
**NO MATCH**
```

or

```
Network is unreachable
```

So you gotta go with a paid plan.
Or find some other method to host your web server.

For the record - what we're doing here is creating a "dumbed-down" web gui version of a cli http client, like `wget` or `curl`.

you could just run in bash / powershell `wget <your-url>` and it would be basically the same.

Comment: To test this without an external web hosting service, `pip install flask requests` on your local machine (preferably in a venv) and run `python flask_app.py`

Answer (score 0):

This code can work, if you want to download a website **on the same domain**.

For example, you can download `https://example.com/main.html` , if your domain is `https://example.com/`

However, if your domain is `https://example2.org/`， it is not working.

The reason why you can not download all pages from the internet is the browser is using [CORB](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/corb-for-developers/) for safety reason.

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
</head>
<button type="button" id="down">Download</button>
<input id="InputURL" placeholder="The URL you want to download." style="width:100%">
<p id="HiddenLable" style="">
  The HTML
</p>
<script language="javascript">
document.getElementById('down').onclick = function () {
  //var filename = "Download.html";
  //var content = "Hello, you download a text file by Javasctipt.";
  //veiwweb(document.getElementById('InputURL').value);
  //var content = document.getElementById("HiddenLable").innerHTML;
  //console.log(content);
  //download("DownLoad.html", content);
  veiwweb(document.getElementById('InputURL').value);
};
  function veiwweb(TheLink){
    if ( window.ActiveXObject )         // windows
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
else if ( window.XMLHttpRequest )   // other sys
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    
    
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = Callback;
xmlHttp.open("GET", TheLink, false ); // read
xmlHttp.send(null); 
  }
  function Callback()
{
  if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 ) {
    if ( xmlHttp.status == 200 ) {
      var value = xmlHttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("HiddenLable").innerHTML = value;
      download("DownLoad.html", value);
    }
  }
}    

  function download(filename, content) { 
    //can not use this function to call viewweb() function because the value may not downloaded yet.
    var blob = new Blob([content], {type: 'text/plain'});
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var a = document.createElement('a');

    a.style = "display: none";
    a.href = url;
    a.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();

    setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 5);
}
  
  
</script>
```

If you tried to download a HTML from a different domain, you can see this in the *console*:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://******/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: "This code can work, if you want to download a website on the same domain." This solution doesn't work for me as the form is supposed to download things form different domains.

Comment: @Mori that is **impossible to just using HTML+JS to achieve it** , you have to use PHP as the browser is using **CORB** . Or you can try if IE can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function downloadUrl(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

If you have anchor element with url, you may fire `element.click()` through code.

```
var element = document.createElement('#your-achnor-tag-id'); //
element.click()
```