# Download a webpage using url

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am building an application and in that, I want to create a download button, which allows the user to download the web page targeted by the URL embedded in that button. Can anyone help me out in this?

[Sample image of post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmZqv.png)

I tried using `<a href="url" download></a>` but it does not work.
P.S: I am using ReactJS to develop my web app.

Comment: "It does not work" – what happens that shouldn't, what doesn't that should? What is the actual `url` you're trying to download?

Comment: So it is like, there is a post and each post is associated with a news snippet. There is a "Read" button which redirects the user to the page where the news is originally posted. I want to add a download button so that, using it, the user  can download the page targeted by that url and view the news offline

Comment: I think that was understood. But what do you mean by "it does not work"? The user will only download the HTML I assume? That's just what browsers do when you visit a URL. What should happen instead? Should the text be copied to the clipboard or do you really want to download the whole page including assets/css/js? Should links be kept the same? Why not simply create a bookmark to the content?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75308401/how-can-i-create-a-button-or-link-that-automatically-downloads-a-file-based-on-a/75394777#75394777) is a similar question.

Answer (score 2):

> There is a "Read" button which redirects the user to the page where the news is originally posted. I want to add a download button so that, using it, the user can download the page targeted by that url and view the news offline

That's not going to happen if the original URL is not on the same origin; [as documented for the `download` attribute](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download),

> `download` only works for same-origin URLs, or the `blob:` and `data:` schemes.

Even if that wasn't a limitation here, you'd only download the HTML for the remote page, which might or might not contain (all of) the content the user wants to see.

Comment: Thanks I didnt know about this. Is there any way I can acheive the intended functionality?

Comment: You would likely need server-side code to download or scrape the target URL, and then send that to your client.